# buildSchema is not a function graphql npm

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

The [official website of graphql](http://graphql.org/code/#graphql-js-graphql-js-github-https-github-com-graphql-graphql-js-npm-https-www-npmjs-com-package-graphql) refers to this [graphql npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql) to create the helloworld .

```
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');

var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

var root = { hello: () => 'Hello world!' };

graphql(schema, '{ hello }', root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

When i run  this file with `node` cmd , I got :

> var schema = buildSchema(`
>                ^
>
> TypeError: buildSchema is not a function
>       at Object. (

I guess the offcial website of graphql is not up-to-date with this repository , so , i tried to use `GraphQLSchema` instead of `buildSchema`

```
var schema = GraphQLSchema(`
  ...
`)
```

I go another error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

Thus , i called `new GraphQLSchema(...` instead of `GraphQLSchema(...`

I got another error :

```
Error: Must provide configuration object.
```

So  , what i did as next step, I explored the object and i filter functions contains `schema` in its name

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const functionsContainsSchema=  Object.keys(graphql).filter(e => e.toLowerCase().includes('schema') && typeof graphql[e] ==='function');
console.log(
   functionsContainsSchema
) 
/* STDOUT
[ 'GraphQLSchema',
  'buildClientSchema',
  'buildASTSchema',
  'extendSchema',
  'printSchema' ]

 */
```

What is the new version of `buildSchema` and what is its signature  ?

Comment: your node version please

Comment: @p0k8_ : `node -v #v7.4.0 ` and `npm -v # 4.0.1`

Comment: What version of the `graphql` module do you have installed? Try deleting the `node_modules` directory and re-installing the latest version of `graphql`. I tried `Object.keys(graphql)` and `buildSchema` is definitely there.

Comment: I'm also stuck with same problem....did u got the answer??